# Warn users when deleting questions or answers with positive anonymous feedback

Tags: feature-request, deleted-posts, post-feedback

While looking through the [anonymous post feedback for my questions and answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts) I noticed that I had deleted some answers (spring cleaning of duplicates, etc) which had received positive feedback from anonymous users.

An absence of upvotes or excessive downvotes may signal a need to delete your post, however, if anonymous feedback indicates the opposite then that post may be a candidate to keep open and improve.

For these reasons, I'm proposing that when a user goes to delete their question or answer that they are alerted if there is positive anonymous feedback for their post.

Comment: would this apply to self-deletion, deletion of other users' content, or both?

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing out that query. I should probably go through and purge some of my posts with negative feedback...

Comment: @Servy: I originally worded it 'their', but likely this is useful information to any deletion.

Comment: Probably not relevant to the question at all, but I think the query should also pull the +/- vote counts on the post as well, and whether it was accepted. The first few I looked at where there was "unhelpful" anonymous feedback, there was either higher "helpful" anonymous feedback, or the answer had multiple up-votes / accepted, or both. So great query, but if folks want to be proactive about it this extra information would be useful.

Comment: What an interesting query. I have an unhelpful flag on an accepted answer with +63/-0. Also multiple "unhelpful" flags on a number of other well received (but less spectacular) answers. Gotta wonder what that is all about.

Comment: @dmckee: I've seen similar things on my higher rated answers. Although, I had a +2 question that had 3 unhelpfuls, so I went and deleted it. It was old and off topic by current standards, so good riddance.